# R - reading parse html file starting from specific line

Tags: html, r, xpath, html-parsing

I am trying to scrape some information from a set of huge parse html files using `htmlTreeParse`. I am extracting the information from the fields I need using `xpathSApply`. The fields are ordered sequentially so the information of the following field is always below the information of the previous field.

The `xpathSApply` function takes forever and I was wondering if there is a way to make it more efficient. I strongly believe the `xpathSApply` function starts reading the parse html file from the beginning and, thus, it reads a lot of html code that has already been read and does not contain any useful data. I was trying to figure out if there was a way to tell `xpathSApply` to start reading from the line where it ended reading the previous time.

The code is as follows:

```
    nomcorpN <- xpathSApply(doc.html, "//*//input[@name='_ctl0:PlaceHolderContenido:nomcorpN']/@value")

    codigoINE <- xpathSApply(doc.html, "//*//input[@name='_ctl0:PlaceHolderContenido:codigoINE']/@value")

    codigo <- xpathSApply(doc.html, "//*//input[@name='_ctl0:PlaceHolderContenido:codigo']/@value")

#...
```

And so on for a lot of different fields. I would like to keep the line where it found the information for `nomcorpN` and start looking for `codigoINE` from that line. Keep the line where it finds `codigoINE` and start looking for `codigo` in that line...

Is there a way to achieve that? 
Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Hard to suggest anything without looking at the html. I'd recommend you to upload your file to a site like dropbox and post the link here. Or if you don't want to reveal all your data, at least provide a dummy file that has the same structure.

Comment: No problem, here it is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lwvfxpcoa0ipwih/FederacionEspanoladeMunicipiosyProvincias.html?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
library(rvest)
read_html(file) %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = "//input[contains(@name,'_ctl0:PlaceHolderContenido')]/@value")%>%
    html_text()
```

It just gives a list of values contained in `input` nodes with name containing  `'_ctl0:PlaceHolderContenido'`.

Or for more detailed information about these nodes:

```
library(rvest)
library(plyr)
read_html(file) %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = "//input[contains(@name,'_ctl0:PlaceHolderContenido')]") %>%
    html_attrs() %>%
    sapply(function(x) as.list(x) %>% as.data.frame) %>%
    do.call(rbind.fill, .)
```

Comment: Works fine! It is much faster. But could you explain me why? Thanks!

Comment: Because we search all the needed nodes in one call instead of searching each of them separately. Functions like `xpathSApply` or `html_nodes` imply passing through the whole document in search of matches. So the less function calls we do - the faster it will be.

Comment: Really appreciate it